# Disable link if a condition is true in a function PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

I have this code,I tried to disable an img with link Javascript :

```
<?php
    $cargasreprobadas = 12;
    $cargatotal = 1;

    function reinscripcion($cargasreprobadas, $cargatotal) {
        if (($cargatotal > 0) && ($cargasreprobadas > 100)) 
        {
            $procede = "PROCEDE";
            echo $procede;
            return;
        }

        if (($cargatotal > 0) && ($cargasreprobadas > 0)) 
        {
            $errorminimoamedio = "PROCEDE RECURSAR ADEUDOS";
            echo $errorminimoamedio;
            return;
        }
    }
    reinscripcion($cargasreprobadas, $cargatotal);

    echo '<div id="imprimir">
        <img src="pdf.png" onclick="window.open(\'printtroncocomun.php\')" width="48px" height="48px"></img>
    </div>';
?>
```

How can I disable the `img` element if the second condition is true in the function?

Comment: EduardoRobles please mark and up-vote the answer for others help. it's your responsibility. thanks

Comment: People says solution worked but they are not interested in marking the answers. Really frustrating. deleting my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $cargasreprobadas = 12;
    $cargatotal = 1;

    function reinscripcion($cargasreprobadas, $cargatotal) {
        if (($cargatotal > 0) && ($cargasreprobadas > 100)) 
        {
            $procede = "PROCEDE";
            echo $procede;
            return false;
        }

        if (($cargatotal > 0) && ($cargasreprobadas > 0)) 
        {
            $errorminimoamedio = "PROCEDE RECURSAR ADEUDOS";
            echo $errorminimoamedio;
            return true;
        }
    }
    $return_ = reinscripcion($cargasreprobadas, $cargatotal);

 $onclick = ($return_ == true) ?'onclick="window.open(\'printtroncocomun.php\')"' : '';

    echo '<div id="imprimir">
        <img src="pdf.png" '. $onclick.' width="48px" height="48px"></img>
    </div>';
?>
```